# $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init' not firing after click link

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

i am using google map with jquery mobile .

i want to get user current location in google map...
in default page ([Default page](http://beta.yazilimsozluk.com)) there are links in footer...
in default page in footer when i click  location it works it goes to location page gives user location...
but in default page  in footer when i click another link such as map and then i click location
`$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init'` does not triggered...the page loads but map does not load .it goes to page in browser and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

works but `$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init'` not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for which it works the first time is that the anchors inside the navigation bar of your first page contain the `rel=external` attribute. This forces a full page refresh when changing page.

```
ex: <a href="Contact.htm" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" rel="external">
```

But `rel="external"` is missing from the anchors inside your footer navigation bar included on the other pages.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank for your answear...i added rel="external" to all page but it does not work...   http://beta.yazilimsozluk.com/

Comment: http://beta.yazilimsozluk.com/index.html  this is default page...when i click map then i click location in the URL there is location URL (http://beta.yazilimsozluk.com/PlacePin.htm)   but it does not load...and when in chrome i look resource there is default page html source not location page(placepin) source

Comment: rel="external" is still missing from the navigation bar anchors. check the source code of your pages.

Comment: view-source:http://beta.yazilimsozluk.com/Index1.htm  in here there is  rel="externel" ...maybe you should clear your cache?                                                            <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" rel="external">Places</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index1.htm" rel="external">Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="PlacePin.htm" rel="external">Location</a></li>

Comment: @ Tolis Emmanouilidis  i should clear cache:) thanks it is work in browser now i moved phonegap as IOS app in app it does not work but it is another business thanks again ....

Comment: and also sometimes it work some times it does not work i will try catch this stituation

Comment: You're welcome :) I've noticed some issues in your source page. The document ready handler should not be used in conjunction with jQuery Mobile. You should use events like http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/ . In addition you could make the maps working after Ajax page transition. I've written a relevant example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051911/can-not-get-multiple-page-jquery-mobile-working-with-google-maps/12060654#12060654

Comment: i changed...i used this $( "#aboutPage" ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {  now no page fired this event:) .    beta.yazilimsozluk.com

Comment: $( '#details' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){  tihs works..do you suggest?